# Ruby: issues with if-statement output

Tags: ruby, if-statement

I am VERY new to Ruby. I was trying to make a simple "How's your day?" kind of thing, but when I answer with "Good" it's supposed to return "Good to hear" but it skips it and goes to my else statement that returns "Not valid". Same thing when I enter "Bad", it's supposed to give me "Oh no" but instead it gives me "Not valid". I know your usually supposed to use ==, but I don't know what I am missing here. Thank you for your help.

```
puts "How are you?"
answer = gets
if (answer == "Good");
    print("Good to hear")
elsif (answer == "Bad");
    print("Oh no")
else;
    print("Not valid")
end
```

Comment: Are those semicolons ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gets` will capture a string including an endline character (`\n`). You're comparing the string `Good` (for example) against `Good\n`, and it obviously doesn't match.

You can observe this by adding a line after you populate `answer`, like `puts answer.inspect` (or more tersely, `p answer`). This will show you the string along with any not-normally-visible characters.

The easiest way to fix this will be to use `answer = gets.strip`, which will remove whitespace characters (including spaces, tabs, and newlines) from end of the captured input string.